# inserting values from userform to excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i need your support, i created userform having many input box and combobox and i am trying to insert data...from userform to excel but i need the insertion to be at the end of the first empty row of my excel sheet.
any help is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)=textbox1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution since next empty row would be lastusedrow + 1

```
    Row = rg.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row + 1
```

or

```
    rg.Cells(Row + 1, 1).Value = Me.txtP.Value
```

Hope this answers your question
for more reference you can look up this site https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/92870-write-data-from-textbox-to-next-empty-row